# Кто как адаптирует декоративные фоновые картинки?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Всем доброго времени суток.Интересно, какие приемы вы используете при адаптации подобных картинок?
[image: картинка]

Я секции about прописал before со стилями для всех экранов плюс пару брейкпойнтов где изменял значение значение left

```
content: ''
position: absolute
bottom: 0
left: 13%
background: url(../img/about-pict.png) no-repeat center
background-size: contain
width: 550px
height: 733px
```

Но такой подход очень неудобен, т.к при увеличении ширины экрана картинка потихоньку съезжает влево, а при уменьшении на определенном значении ширины начинает налазить на текст.Приходится прописывать кучу брейкпойнтов для left.На 4к картинка вообще далеко от текста.В container сетки она не влезает, выпирает слева.

Comment: попробуйте привязать к контейнеру и от него отталкиваться

Comment: А зачем ставить `left` в %? Логично, что будет уезжать.

Вариантов много, но логика же должна быть. Например, если картинка не должна налазить на (или залезать под) текст, ее лучше вынести в отдельный контейнер. Если должна, то расстояние от края контейнера до текста и картинки не должно плавать, например, `background-position` и `padding` задать жестко.